# C++ Read txt file from directory

Tags: c++

I have a code that reads all the .txt file in the directory.. Then the user will select what .txt file he/she wants to see.

My code works if i will remove the code inside the comment  "START READING FILE". But if it is included in my code, it does not work and shows an error "**cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void' to 'const char *'**"

I don't know whats wrong with my code.. I think its because that I use this..

```
ifstream myfile(get_txt(0,select,0));
```

Instead of

```
ifstream myfile("example.txt");
```

Anyone who can help me? Heres my code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
string Chop(string &str){
    string res = str;
    int len = str.length();
    if (str[len - 1] == '\r'){
        res.replace(len - 1, 1, "");
    }
    len = str.length();
    if (str[len - 1] == '\n'){
        res.replace(len - 1, 1, "");
    }
    return res;
}
void DumpEntry(_finddata_t &data){
    string createtime(ctime(&data.time_create));
    if ((data.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) == _A_SUBDIR){
        cout << "[" << data.name << "]" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << data.name << endl;
    }
}

void get_txt(int num, int ind, int all){
    int ctr=1;
    _finddata_t data;
    int ff = _findfirst ("*.txt*", &data);
    if (ff != -1){
        int res = 0;
        while (res != -1){  
            if(num==1){
                cout << ctr << ". ";
                DumpEntry(data);
            }
            else if(ctr==ind){
                DumpEntry(data);
            }
                res = _findnext(ff, &data);
                ctr++;
        }
    _findclose(ff);
        if(all==1){
            cout << ctr-1;
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int ctr = 0, select;
    get_txt(1,0,0);
    cout << "Select from 1-"; get_txt(0,0,1); cout << " files: ";
    cin >> select;
    get_txt(0,select,0);

    //START READING FILE
      string line;
      ifstream myfile(get_txt(0,select,0));
      if (myfile.is_open()){
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
          cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
      }

      else{ 
          cout << "Unable to open file"; 
      }
    // END READING FILE


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ifstream` takes in a string or character array, you're passing it a void function. What exactly do you want to be opening? Also, I would expect a function named `get_text` to return a string or character array, but yours doesn't return anything, hence, the issue.

Comment: It's because `get_txt` doesn't actually *return* a value. You could modify it to create a vector of strings, and then use those strings to open the files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can you provide the code? Sorry, but vectors is not really familiar on me. Please forgive me.

Comment: @David What i want is the text output of get_text will be use to ifstream. Is it possible? Sorry. Can you provide the code? Huhu

Comment: When you would post code only to the problem you have you would realize that your function `get_txt` doesn't return a value. Instead it dumps something to the console. Let it return a `std::string` (initialized witht the value of `data.name`) when the condition `(ctr==ind)` matches.

Comment: Yep, what @harper said.